# WPF. Определить через код, "переполнен" ли Label?

Tags: c#, wpf, ui, label

Label использую для показа текущего пути к необходимым файлам. Как определить через код, хватает ли длины Label для показа полного пути?
Размера формы может не хватить для его показа, поэтому при слишком длинном пути хочу сокращать строку при выводе на форму. Как-то так: "C:\...\Required Files"

Comment: На самом деле, вам нужно не только это. Вам нужно для строки определить, какую ширину она реально будет занимать, чтобы не выкинуть слишком много. В любом случае, вопрос валидный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужен метод [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9bt8ty58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Я пока искал ответ на вопрос, нашёл такой вариант     `Label_Path.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity))` - и всё работает: если после этого проверить свойство `Label_Path.DesiredSize`, то будет не double бесконечность, а тот, что нужен. Но тогда вариант показался бредом, и не стал проверять. Не знаете, почему так работает? Указывается бесконечность ведь.

Comment: @Max: Потому что аргументом для Measure является констрейнт. Если вы указываете бесконечность, вы тем самым просите размер, который имел бы текст, если не ограничивать его — то есть, длину неужатого текста.

Comment: @VladD, хм, спасибо, этот момент более ясен, хотя суть Measure я всё равно не могу понять. maestro, спасибо

Comment: @Max: Для layout management'а используются две функции — Measure и Arrange. Сначала контейнер узнаёт, сколько хочет каждый из дочерних элементов, исходя из доступного места (Measure + DesiredSize), а потом выделяет им, сколько они получат в реальности (Arrange).

Comment: @VladD, класс, спасибо большое.